# Why is readObject of StringBuffer not synchronized?

Tags: java, serialization, synchronization

If you look into the `StringBuffer`'s source you will see:

```
/**
 * readObject is called to restore the state of the StringBuffer from
 * a stream.
 */
private synchronized void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.PutField fields = s.putFields();
    fields.put("value", value);
    fields.put("count", count);
    fields.put("shared", false);
    s.writeFields();
}

/**
 * readObject is called to restore the state of the StringBuffer from
 * a stream.
 */
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
    throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField fields = s.readFields();
    value = (char[])fields.get("value", null);
    count = fields.get("count", 0);
}
```

<del>Why can it not be happen that two Objects are desynchronized from two different resources?</del>

Why can it not be happen that one Object is <del>desynchronized</del> deserialized from two different resources?

See my example:

```
    final ObjectInputStream objectInputABC=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ABC"));
    final ObjectInputStream objectInputDE=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("DE"));

    final ObjectStreamClass osc = new ObjectStreamClass();
    final StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer) objectInputABC.readObject();
    osc.invokeReadObject(sb,objectInputDE);
```

Comment: `readObject` is presumably called when an object is being "freshly" deserialized from an ObjectInputStream and no other cade can yet have a reference to it.

Comment: Why would it be synchronized? You call this method at object initialization stage; when it is called it is not yet shared

Comment: "Why can it not be happen that two Objects are desynchronized from different resources?" doesn't make sense. If you mean 'deserialized', it *can* happen, but that doesn't require synchronization. What makes you think it does?

Comment: @EJP If readObject is called in *ThreadA* for `ABC` and *ThreadB* for `DE` at the same time the order may be: *ThreadA* `value` to `ABC`, ThreadB `value` to `DE`, ThreadB `count` to `2`, ThreadA `count` to `3`. Now you have value `DE` and count `3`.

Comment: If two objects are deserialized, which is what I assume you mean, from two different streams at the same time, there is zero shared state anywhere that needs synchronization. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP Not for two objects, for one object only. Using `ObjectStreamClass ` in example.

Comment: You can't deserialize one object from two streams. Two deserializations yields two objects. The question still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your new example doesn't represent a case that needs synchronization. Two threads that invoke it will get distinct values for `sb`, as @jtahlborn's comment and Duncan's answer both state. The part where you create an `ObjectStreamClass` via a private or possibly non-existent constructor in order to call the private or possibly non-existent `invokeReadObject()` method on the wrong stream doesn't even compile, and if it did it would just be an abuse of the API, not a proof that synchronization is required. This is making no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP This tells me SB is threadsave because noone actually can use it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readObject()` is only called during the construction of a new object from a serialized stream. There is no scope for two threads to execute this method at the same time on the same object.

Conversely, two threads may try to serialize the same object at the same time, hence `writeObject` is synchronized.

Comment: It looks to me like its part of the magic to call private functions while serialization/deserialization. Any official documentation?

Comment: @PeterRader The Javadocs for [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) explain the methods, but they don't answer your complete question. What part exactly do you want references for?

Comment: @PeterRader The official documentation is the Object Serialization Specification.